# Express.js throw exception and return pre-defined status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, exception

In spring i use define my own class extending `Exception` annotate it with `@ResponseStatus` to throw it in specific situation to return to user specific status code and error message. I'd like to do something similar in `Express.js` in `Node.js`. Is it possible?

Now I use `Q` to return rejected promise from `loginService` and return explicitly response code and message.

```
router.post('/log-in', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  loginService.authenticate(req.body.userLogin, req.body.userPassword)
    .then((successLogin)=>{
    res.json(successLogin);
    }, function (error) {
      res.status(error.code).json({message: error.reason});
    })
});
```

but my goal is to handle only resolved promises and throw whenever an error occurred. something like

```
router.post('/log-in', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  loginService.authenticate(req.body.userLogin, req.body.userPassword)
    .then((successLogin)=>{
    res.json(successLogin);
    })
});
```

and I imagine service throwing like

```
if(!user) new Error(404, 'Cannot find user')
```

and response returned to user would have desired code and message. Is it possible to implement it in Node? Would it be efficient?